# Regex Get only docx or doc value from href

Tags: regex, hyperlink, href

After searching in stackoverflow, I have found this regex pattern:

```
/href=['"]([^'"]+?)['"]/
```

it gets all `href`s' values.

Now I need to restrict that pattern to get only doc or docx values.

Note that link may end with additions after `.docx` or `.doc`.

For example, if I have the link:

```
<a href="/site/file1.doc?id=1">link1</a>
```

Result should be:

```
/site/file1.doc
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get only doc or docx values". Are you wanting to capture the extension, or do you only want the `href` value to match if it is doc/docx?

Comment: What flavor of Regex?  Will file name always be preceded by a slash?

Comment: I meant value which starts after href until .doc or .docx, for example if i have <a href="/site1/site2/file.doc?id=1">bbb</a>
result should be: /site1/site2/file.doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/href=(['"])([^'"]+\.docx?(\?[^'"]*)?)\1/
```

This requires that what comes after ".doc" or ".docx" is either the end of the href, *or* a question mark followed by stuff, ie it won't match "foo.doctor".

This also ensures that the quotes match at each end via a back reference.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/RNFtb48YqT).

Answer (score 0):

```
/href=['"]([^'"]+?\.docx?)[^'"]['"]/
```

check it out here: https://regex101.com/r/oS1cD0/2

Comment: This will match "foo.doctor"